# How to add / use default icons to navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, ios-icons

I want to use some of default [iOS icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarButtonSystemItem) i.e.
[image]

in navigation bar.
Basically I don't know how to call image of that item (directly from native library - I know how to download it and place as custom image:)):

```
   var myButton:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
   myButton.addTarget(self, action: "reload", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   myButton.setImage(???, forState: <#UIControlState#>)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `UIBarButtonSystemItem` this way:

```
let button = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, target: self, action: "someAction")
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = button
```

Result for `leftBarButtonItem`:

[image]

If you want to set it at right side you can use this code:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
```

Result for `rightBarButtonItem`:

[image]

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 11):

**Swift:** These are the most commonly used options:

To Use custom image with original colour:

```
let customImageBarBtn1 = UIBarButtonItem(
    UIImage(named: "someImage.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal),
    style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleClick))
```

To Use custom image with tint colour:

```
let customImageBarBtn2 = UIBarButtonItem(
    UIImage(named: "someImage.png").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate),
    style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleClick))
```

Or use system provided buttons:

```
let systemBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: .search,
    target: self, action: #selector(handleClick))
```

Then add any one of these buttons to the navigationItem:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [customImageBarBtn1, customImageBarBtn2]
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [systemBarBtn]
// OR you can use this if there's only one item.
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = systemBarBtn
```

**For custom Images:** As a starting size, `22ptx22pt` images work well for the default iPhone Navigation Bar size.

Comment: Thanks. So easy. then just add a func handleClick

Answer (score 1):

In swift 4.3

```
let btnRefresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.refresh, target: self, action: #selector(targeted function to invoke))

   //If you want icon in left side
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnRefresh

   //If you want icon in right side
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btnRefresh
```