# How to get all the system icons in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button

I want to be able to use the camera switch icon that is listed here not the plain one the switch one.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html

But in Xcode under my bar button item it does not seem to be listed?
[image]

I understand I am probably missing something blatantly obvious. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558014/ios-how-to-add-use-default-icons-to-navigation-bar-in-swift)?

Comment: Just looking at this does this mean i have to download a icon library from somewhere? as it doesnt mention the camera switch icon?

Answer (score 8):

We are talking about [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/BarIcons.html) like

[image]

Your aim is to grab the 1x and 2x icons?
There are several online resources (free and paid), but I assume your aim is to get those icons from the device directly in some way.

Those are the ones coming from the `UITabBarItem` init with `TabBarSystemItem`

```
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:0]
```

If you are going to extract all of them, see [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/2009/01/03/extracting-sdk-icons/) to have an idea.

If you want just to list them, taking a look at the headers you will find

```
typedef enum {
   UITabBarSystemItemMore,
   UITabBarSystemItemFavorites,
   UITabBarSystemItemFeatured,
   UITabBarSystemItemTopRated,
   UITabBarSystemItemRecents,
   UITabBarSystemItemContacts,
   UITabBarSystemItemHistory,
   UITabBarSystemItemBookmarks,
   UITabBarSystemItemSearch,
   UITabBarSystemItemDownloads,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostRecent,
   UITabBarSystemItemMostViewed,
} UITabBarSystemItem;
```

Comment: Is there a flip camera icon built-in?

Comment: According to the Apple's `System Icons` docs https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/ there is not. By the way here is a nice one: https://dribbble.com/shots/1819004-iOS-8-Flip-Camera-Icon

Answer (score 0):

My 5cnt 
Since iOS 13 I think the proper way would be to use [SF-Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) (just download the app). They are free and configurable
([Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) )